# Unable to call opportunity name from list

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch

I have a Batch Class where it sends an email when Expiry Date (Custom Date Field) is today. The mail body contains the list of opportunities whose Expiry Date is Today. I have created a list and added the opportunities whose Expiry Date is today. But I am stuck at calling Opportunity Name from the List. Can someone help me to solve this.

//Batch Class

```
global class OpportunityExpiryDate_New implements DataBase.Batchable <sObject> {
    global DataBase.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Name, Expiry_Date__c  FROM Opportunity WHERE Expiry_Date__c = TODAY';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope) {
        List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity opp : scope) {
            if(opp.Expiry_Date__c == date.today()) {
                oppList.add(opp);
            }
        }
        update oppList;
        messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String body = 'The Opportunity ' +oppList+ ' is expiring today.';
        email.setToAddresses(new String[]{'maddulasaivineeth@gmail.com'});
        email.setSubject('Opportunities Expiring Today');
        email.setPlainTextBody(body);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to present Opportunity names, accumulate those names in a `List<String>`, instead of accumulating the Opportunities themselves:

```
    List<String> oppNames = new List<String>();
    for(Opportunity opp : scope) {
        oppNames.add(opp.Name);
    }
```

You don't need that `if` statement because that filtering is already accomplished by your query.

Then, generate (for example) a comma-separated list with the static method [`String.join()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#!):

```
String.join(oppNames, ', ')
```

and use that wherever you need it.